# How to get the root Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The code below is a dreadful hack.

```
Uri linkUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
string link = linkUri.ToString().Substring(0, linkUri.ToString().IndexOf("Users/Create"));
```

Instead of editing the string, how do I get the correct route Url in the first place?

For example I want to get `http://localhost:9999/` instead of `http://localhost:9999/Users/Create`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's pretty ugly, but how about:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9999/Users/Create");
string link = string.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}", uri.Scheme, uri.Host, uri.Port);
```

Edit: or even better:

```
uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
```

Comment: Yes this is certainly an improvement. I will wait and see what other answers I get, but this is the best so far.

Answer (score 20):

You could use the [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx) method of `UrlHelper`:

```
string root = urlHelper.Content("~/");
```

Comment: I get an error message; "An object reference is required for the non-static field method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Content(string)'"

Comment: Yes, you need a reference to an UrlHelper. If you are writing this code in a controller you already have the `Url` property on which you could invoke the `Content` method. If it is in a view: `<%= Url.Content("~/") %>`.

Comment: I am not using this code in a View. I am coding within a class, where UrlHelper does not have a Content method.

Comment: you can use inside controller (new UrlHelper(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext)).Content("~/")

Comment: I only seem to be getting the "/"

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I suggest embedding the content of your comment in the body of the answer (as the current answer doesn't actually 'compile') **Url.Content("~")** for the win!

Answer (score 3):

[Making Sense of ASP.NET Paths - Rick Strahl's Web Log](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/132081.aspx)

How about this?
Request.ApplicationPath

Comment: I can only access the Request object as follows; HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath. All this returns is a "/".

Answer (score 2):

```
var rootUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```